# jQuery Datepicker - Display next 7 Days outside the calendar widget

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using jQuery datepicker to display available days for booking a trip.

```
var array = ['07.12.2013', '11.12.2013', '25.12.2013', '08.01.2014', '22.01.2014', '05.02.2014', '19.02.2014', '05.03.2014', '19.03.2014'];
            $('#tripDate').datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                firstDay: 1,
                minDate: +2,
                showOn: "both",
                buttonImage: "images/cal.png",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                beforeShowDay: function unavailable(date) {
                    var f = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', date)
                            var tooltipDate = "Cruise Ship AIDA";
                            var tooltipNoTour = "NO Tour on this Date!";
                            var tooltipClosed = "Marine Park Closed - NO Tours";
                    var day = date.getDay();
                    var month = date.getMonth();
                    var year = date.getYear();
                    if ($.inArray(f, array) > -1) {
                        return [false , '' , tooltipDate];
                    } else if (month == 10) {
                        return [false , '' , tooltipClosed];
                    } else if (month == 3 || month == 4 || month == 5 || month == 8 || month == 9) {
                            if ((day == 3) || (day == 5) || (day == 0)) {
                        return [false, '', tooltipNoTour];
                        }
                        else {
                                    return [true, '', ''];
                        }
                    } else {
                            if (day == 0) {
                            return [false, '' , tooltipNoTour];
                        }
                        else {
                                        return [true, '', '']; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

I now want to show the next 7 days (from today) outside the datepicker in a list with days available in green and days unavailable in red.
How can I get the days from the datepicker to display?

Comment: "I now want to show the next 7 days (from today) outside the datepicker in a list with days available in green and days unavailable in red." what do you mean by outside? Can you provide a mockup or a fiddle?

Comment: With ourside I mean in a separet Table or Div. The idea behind it is to show the customer available Days with the number of available spaces for the tour.

Comment: But the table/div is inside the datepicker or outside? 7 days always from today or from the selected day?

Comment: The table/Div should be outside the datepicker (I'm using the popup for the calendar). 7 days from today would be the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract your `beforeShowDay` function in an external function and in DOMREADY get the current date and populate a little table with the next seven days.

For each day you'll check the aviability of the day and color accordingly the background.

Code:

```
$('#tripDate').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: +2,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/cal.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    beforeShowDay: function unavailable(date) {
        return isAviable(date)
    }
});

$("#avialableDays tr td").each(function (i, o) {
    var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + i+1);
    $(this).text(myDate.getDate());
    (isAviable(myDate)[0] == true) ? $(this).addClass('green') : $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tAr26/2/